# Giving away upvote: is it doing any good?

Tags: discussion, voting

I have seen that some users here are quite liberal in dispensing upvotes.

I am generally not in  favor of such liberality, but also not against it.

Personally I give upvotes when I see something good, but I can understand that some prefer to give upvotes when they don't see anything bad. As I said above, I can live with it.

However, once in a while I stumble in cases like the one below:

[image]

- It's not an answer to the question
- It's blatant nonsense/trolling

Whoever gave that upvote to the answer, what exactly was hoping to achieve?

Please be considerate when upvoting. Your upvote is shaping the content you like in this community.

Comment: There is an additional problem of the Hot Network Questions. People can land on this site and vote up with their association bonus. But they cannot downvote. Moreover, people with associative bonus don't always vote according to the site's purpose or post quality. So HNQ targets can receive disproportionate votes. It's a problem across the network.

Comment: Given the nature of the post you mention, I think the upvoter is either a bot, a puppet account or someone gaming the system in a malicious way.

Comment: Honestly, I can imagine upvoting something like that for the sake of humour. I know it's wrong, but I can imagine being in a droll mood and doing that.

Comment: Even downvoting an answer like that is a waste of time and effort. Personally I'd flag it as spam and be done with it.

Answer (score -1):

I think giving upvote is a good way to encourage people to participate in the community, especially who ask question.

If I see the question is long and have some content (not random character), I will give upvote as a way to reward people for participate.

I will also give upvote for answer who spent time writing (thoughtful answer) rather than correct answer (in the case of worldbuilding, correctness might not importance as creativity, not in other stackexchange).

Comment: You misunderstand; this Meta question is about upvoting random nonsense answers, not about upvoting in general.

Comment: @F1Krazy - To be fair, L Dutch opened the door when, in the body of the question, he states his own rationales, *Personally I give upvotes...*.  Also, the query title, as worded, is just fuzzy and unfocused enough to allow for a broad discussion of this type. Clearly, this response answers the question "is it doing any good".